# Finding conditional expectation of $Y$ given $X$

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, expected-value

> We select a number $X$ at random from $\{-3 , -1 , 0 , 2 , 5 \}$. If $X\le 0$ then we choose $Y$ randomly from $[X-2 , X+3]$ otherwise from $[-X , X]$ interval. Calculate value of $\mathbb{E}[Y]$.

**My try:** I think we should use iterated law of expectation. Namely, $\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]]$ and then $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]] = \sum \mathbb{E}[Y|x_k]P_X(x_k)$ but I don't know how to compute $\mathbb{E}[Y|x_k]$ and also this way seems too long.

Comment: Your idea is good. What's wrong with it? All $P_X(x_k)$ are just $\frac{1}{5}$, which can be factored out. For the positive $x_k$, $E[Y|x_k]=0$ since the midpoint of $[-x_k,x_k]$ is zero. Then you just have three more. I can probably arrive at the answer in my head; it's not that much work. It should be $- 2.5/5 = -1/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the law of iterated expectation. Condition on the partition $\{\{X\le 0\},\{X>0\}\}$ to get

$$\mathbb E[Y]=\mathbb E[Y\mid X\le 0]\mathbb P\{X\le 0\}+\mathbb E[Y\mid X>0]\mathbb P\{X>0\}$$

When $X\le 0$, it is given that $Y$ has a uniform distribution on $[X-2,X+3]$; otherwise $Y$ is uniform on $[-X,X]$. This information gives you

\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Y\mid X\le 0]&=\sum_{j\le 0} \mathbb E[Y\mid X=j]\mathbb P\{X=j\mid X\le 0\}
\\&=\frac1{\mathbb P\{X\le 0\}}\sum_{j\in\{-3,-1,0\}} \mathbb E[Y\mid X=j]\mathbb P\{X=j\}
\\&=\frac1{\mathbb P\{X\le 0\}}\sum_{j\in\{-3,-1,0\}} \left(\frac{j-2+j+3}{2}\right)\cdot\frac15
\\&=\cdots
\end{align}

Since $\mathbb E[Y\mid X=j]=\frac{-j+j}{2}=0$ for $j\in\{2,5\}$, you have $\mathbb E[Y\mid X>0]=0$ by a similar argument.